# phoneGap 4.2.0 and Xcode 6.1.1 camera and album error

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, camera, phonegap-build

I have designed and developed an app with phoneGap. And now I have camera and album errors building it in Xcode. It just does not work.
In phoneGap emulator camera works fine. But not in real build.
Is it possible that I need to add some framework or lib in .xcodeproj, generated by phoneGap (codovra)? Should I change some settings?
My build does not ask for camera or album permission. But PhoneGap Developer app asked for it.

Here is the code, but I don't think it is the problem.

```
$scope.cameraError = function(message) {
        console.log(message);
    };
    $scope.getPicture = function(source) {
        var options = {
            quality: 50,
            targetWidth: 1000,
            targetHeight: 1000,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            sourceType: source
        };
        navigator.camera.getPicture($scope.pictureUpload, $scope.cameraError, options);
    };
    $scope.takePicture = function() {
        return $scope.getPicture(Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA);
    };
    $scope.loadLibrary = function() {
        return $scope.getPicture(Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY);
    };
```

Comment: Also libCordova.a is red. And I don't have any idea how to link it to the project :(

Comment: What are you referring to when you say `But phoneGap emulator asked for it.`? There is no actual phonegap emulator, are you talking about the PhoneGap Developer app?

Comment: @DawsonLoudon  Yes Mr. Loudon. I'm talking about an app.

Comment: I think we have found an error. Here https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/885 Adobe say that last phonegap version supporting camera plugin is 3.7.0. It is strange, but it seems like the only reason camera does not work in our app. But i'm not sure. It would be very "original" of phonegap team not to support their own plugin in newer versions.

Comment: PhoneGap has fragmented versioning. 4.2.0 is the version of the CLI, 3.7.0 is the version of the iOS build.

Comment: Without having all the details I believe this is your issue: You are using something like `phonegap serve` to run your code from the `PhoneGap Developer App` which you are downloading from the app store. BUT when you build the app locally using something like `phonegap build` and run your build of the app, the camera does not work. The reason is that Developer app has the plugins pre-installed. To get them to work in your local build you have to run `phonegap plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera` before you build and run the app.

Comment: what is your error message?

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin there is no messages at all. Button calling camera just don't do anything.

Comment: try do console.log(). check either your function triggering or not.

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin unfortunately for us, we have runed "phonegap plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera" at the start of the developement. So it is not our case :(
console.log() does not work with Xcode as well. Do you have any other thoughts?

Comment: add this plugin for console.log . https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a lot of questions about phoneGap. And all the answers are mostly about right installation of plugins and other simple stuff. So in my case problem was in the wrong path to cordova.js. So be patient to analyse your code in case of errors with phoneGap.

**Stay calm and keep coding :D**